# Sequences of coin tosses without consecutive heads

Tags: probability, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $X$ be the number of coin tosses needed until you first get two heads in a row.
>   (Note that $X \geq 2$.) Find the probability mass function of $X$. Find the probability generating function of $X$. Use this to calculate the mean of $X$.

Here's my attempt. First, I calculate the probability that a sequence of $n$ tosses doesn't have two consecutive heads.

Let's denote by $p_n$ the probability that a sequence of $n$ tosses doesn't have any two consecutive heads.

Denote by $T_{n}$ the number of sequences of $n$ tosses that don't have two consecutive heads and that end with a tail, and $H_{n}$ the number of sequences of $n$ tosses that don't have two consecutive heads and that end with a head. Also, call $A_n$ the number of sequence of $n$ tosses that don't have two consecutive heads. Then

$$H_n=T_{n-1}$$
$$T_n=H_{n-1}+T_{n-1}=T_{n-2}+T_{n-1}$$
$$A_n= A_{n-1}+T_{n-1}=A_{n-1}+H_{n-2}+T_{n-2}=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}.$$

As $A_1=1$ and $A_2=3$, we get that $A_n=f_{n+1}$ (the $n+1$-th Fibonacci Number). So $p_n$ is equal to this number divided by the total possible number of sequences ($2^n$).

At this point, I return to calculating $P(X)$.

The probability that at least $k$ tosses are needed is equal to the probability that a run of $k-1$ tosses doesn't have two consecutive heads. That is to say,
$$P(X\geq k) = p_{k-1} = \frac{f_{n}}{2^{n-1}}.$$
Also,
$$P(X>k) = p_{k} = \frac{f_{n+1}}{2^{n}}.$$
So
$$P(X=k) = p_{k-1}-p_{k}=\frac{2f_{n}-f_{n+1}}{2^{n}}=\frac{f_{n-2}}{2^{n}}$$

So the generating function would be

$$G(s)=\sum_{k\geq 0}s^k\frac{f_{k-2}}{2^{k}}$$
and so
$$G'(1) = \sum_{k\geq 0}k\frac{f_{k-2}}{2^{k}}.$$

Is this last sum correct, and if so, how can I calculate it?